# jQuery - How do I add target="_blank" to external links in generated text

Tags: jquery

I need to add target="_blank" to all external links on my site normally I would use:

```
$("a[href^=http]").each(function(){
    if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
        $(this).attr({
            target: "_blank",
            title: "Opens in a new window"
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately the links I need to check for are inside a div with the id of messageArea, and since they are generated via an ajax call, they arent getting picked up.

I could use c# regex functions and rewrite the content or add the target="_blank" but I would rather leave the content in its orginal state.

Any suggestions?

---

Using lucuma's suggestion the solution is:

```
$.getJSON(
   "ajax/GetMessage.aspx?message=" + msgID,
   function (msgs) {
       $("div#messageArea").html(msgs.responseText);
       $("div#messageArea a[href^=http]").each(function(){
           if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
               $(this).attr({
                   target: "_blank",
                   title: "Opens in a new window"
               });
           }
       });
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you wire a call to this function to the ajax.success event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the return from the ajax call add this code:

```
$("div#messageArea a[href^=http]").each(function(){
    if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
        $(this).attr({
            target: "_blank",
            title: "Opens in a new window"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You might be able to make this more generic by attaching it to any Ajax request using this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
```

[all is work](http://jsfiddle.net/heFNv/) Maybe you can show more code?